# No cursor cant click 16.04 Lenovo E460

Tags: 16.04, lenovo, cursor

After I suspended my cursor disappeared and I cant click anything. Ctrl F1 Ctrl F7 as others have proposed does not work.

Comment: This is a known and fixed bug https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xserver-xorg-video-intel/+bug/1568604 Update your system and reboot `sudo apt dist-upgrade && sudo reboot`

Comment: Did not resolve the issue.

Comment: Then you need to report that on the bug report, not here. Only the devs can fix it.

Comment: Yes I will try that, is there no temporary solution as of now?

Comment: Seems from the bug report some users had success by enabeling `proposed updates` in the software and up[dates app and the running a `sudo apt dist-upgrade` seems worth a try.

Answer (score 1):

Editing the grub file from

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""
```

to

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="i8042.reset i8042.nomux i8042.nopnp i8042.noloop"
```

and then updating grub solved the problem.